# getting correct certificate info for offlineimap from outlook imap server

Tags: ssl, outlook, imap

I'm trying to use offlineimap to download Outlook.com messages, but can't seem to get the security correct (I use offlineimap successfully for other IMAP accounts as well). In .offlineimaprc, in the remote repository section, I've put:

```
[Repository remoteOutlook]
type = IMAP
remotehost = imap-mail.outlook.com
ssl = yes 
cert_fingerprint = c914dd966dbd0912c36ec294f83d8d3b5a434729
remoteport = 993
remoteuser = <hidden>
remotepass = <hidden>
```

The fingerprint was captured using gnutls-cli, as follows:

```
$ gnutls-cli -p 993 imap-mail.outlook.com
Processed 168 CA certificate(s).
Resolving 'imap-mail.outlook.com'...
Connecting to '157.56.195.250:993'...
- Certificate type: X.509
- Got a certificate list of 2 certificates.
- Certificate[0] info:
 - subject `C=US,ST=Washington,L=Redmond,O=Microsoft Corporation,CN=*.hotmail.com', issuer `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2015-12-15 22:26:11 UTC', expires `2016-12-15 22:26:11 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `c914dd966dbd0912c36ec294f83d8d3b5a434729'
        Public Key ID:
                e74e1f5a4a2656b5bbf73ae68e293e43a0846941
        Public key's random art:
                +--[ RSA 2048]----+
                |   .E            |
                |    .            |
                |     +      .    |
                |    + . .  . .   |
                |   . . .S.o .    |
                |      .  +.  .   |
                |        o.= +    |
                |       . *+= =+  |
                |         .=+==++.|
                +-----------------+

- Certificate[1] info:
 - subject `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - SHA256 - G2', issuer `C=BE,O=GlobalSign nv-sa,OU=Root CA,CN=GlobalSign Root CA', RSA key 2048 bits, signed using RSA-SHA256, activated `2014-02-20 10:00:00 UTC', expires `2024-02-20 10:00:00 UTC', SHA-1 fingerprint `902ef2deeb3c5b13ea4c3d5193629309e231ae55'
- Status: The certificate is trusted. 
- Description: (TLS1.0)-(ECDHE-RSA-SECP384R1)-(AES-256-CBC)-(SHA1)
- Session ID: 82:4B:00:00:4D:3C:F0:07:B9:B1:49:21:9F:95:99:A9:8B:E4:A7:44:21:6F:06:F6:15:6D:76:F5:F6:3F:4C:97
- Ephemeral EC Diffie-Hellman parameters
 - Using curve: SECP384R1
 - Curve size: 384 bits
- Version: TLS1.0
- Key Exchange: ECDHE-RSA
- Cipher: AES-256-CBC
- MAC: SHA1
- Compression: NULL
- Options: extended master secret, safe renegotiation,
- Handshake was completed

- Simple Client Mode:

* OK Outlook.com IMAP4rev1 server version 17.4.0.0 ready (DUB451-IMAP396)
*** Fatal error: The TLS connection was non-properly terminated.
*** Server has terminated the connection abnormally.
```

This output shows two certificates (0 and 1), with respective SHA1 fingerprints,

```
c914dd966dbd0912c36ec294f83d8d3b5a434729
902ef2deeb3c5b13ea4c3d5193629309e231ae55
```

If I use the first one (as shown in .offlineimaprc above), offlineimap fails to authenticate correctly, and the response is "BAD ['SASL Token argument is missing or invalid.']":

```
$ offlineimap -o
XOAUTH2 authentication failed: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD ['SASL Token argument is missing or invalid.']. Data: FBPH2 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2

PLAIN authentication failed: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
LOGIN authentication failed: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
ERROR: All authentication types failed:
        XOAUTH2: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD ['SASL Token argument is missing or invalid.']. Data: FBPH2 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2

        PLAIN: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
        LOGIN: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: All authentication types failed:
        XOAUTH2: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD ['SASL Token argument is missing or invalid.']. Data: FBPH2 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2

        PLAIN: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.
        LOGIN: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid username or password.

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 271, in syncrunner
    self.__sync()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 334, in __sync
    remoterepos.getfolders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 448, in getfolders
    imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 525, in acquireconnection
    self.__authn_helper(imapobj)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 437, in __authn_helper
    "failed:\n\t%s"% msg, OfflineImapError.ERROR.REPO)
```

Alternatively, if I use the second, offlineimap reports that actually the first fingerprint is the one that the outlook server uses, but as shown previously that one fails, insisting that the username/password is bad.

```
$ offlineimap -o
ERROR: Server SSL fingerprint 'c914dd966dbd0912c36ec294f83d8d3b5a434729' for hostname 'imap-mail.outlook.com' does not match configured fingerprint(s) ['902ef2deeb3c5b13ea4c3d5193629309e231ae55'].  Please verify and set 'cert_fingerprint' accordingly if not set yet.
ERROR: Exceptions occurred during the run!
ERROR: Server SSL fingerprint 'c914dd966dbd0912c36ec294f83d8d3b5a434729' for hostname 'imap-mail.outlook.com' does not match configured fingerprint(s) ['902ef2deeb3c5b13ea4c3d5193629309e231ae55'].  Please verify and set 'cert_fingerprint' accordingly if not set yet.

Traceback:
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 271, in syncrunner
    self.__sync()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/accounts.py", line 334, in __sync
    remoterepos.getfolders()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/repository/IMAP.py", line 448, in getfolders
    imapobj = self.imapserver.acquireconnection()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imapserver.py", line 511, in acquireconnection
    af=self.af,
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imaplibutil.py", line 194, in __init__
    super(WrappedIMAP4_SSL, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 2135, in __init__
    IMAP4.__init__(self, host, port, debug, debug_file, identifier, timeout, debug_buf_lvl)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/bundled_imaplib2.py", line 357, in __init__
    self.open(host, port)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/offlineimap/imaplibutil.py", line 213, in open
    OfflineImapError.ERROR.REPO)
```

I've checked username and password several times (I use the same setup in mutt, and this works fine in terms of accessing the outlook IMAP server). Can anyone tell me what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I should have paid more attention to the very first error message:

```
XOAUTH2 authentication failed: AUTHENTICATE command error: BAD ['SASL Token argument is missing or invalid.']. Data: BFKO2 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2
```

Apparently, as discussed [in this archlinux forum thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1588425#p1588425), the default authentication order in offlineimap is

```
auth_mechanisms = GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, XOAUTH2, PLAIN, LOGIN
```

In order for OAUTH2 to work, as detailed [here](https://github.com/OfflineIMAP/offlineimap/blob/master/offlineimap.conf#L807) additional settings need to be present in .offlineimaprc:

```
oauth2_client_secret = ...
oauth2_client_id = ...
oauth2_refresh_token = ...
```

So the first certificate fingerprint **is** indeed correct, the error is just a notice that XOAUTH2 failed, which can be suppressed simply by specifying the authentication protocols explicitly, and removing XOAUTH2 from the list:

```
auth_mechanisms = GSSAPI, CRAM-MD5, PLAIN, LOGIN
```

I will give setting up XOAUTH2 a shot and post back.